# What is the solution for Sass error on npm watch

Tags: html, css, npm, sass

I already installed my sass globally

```
npm install -g sass
```

but when I run my command line `sass --watch scss:styles/css`

I got an error:

> zsh: command not found: sass

Comment: `npm run sass --watch scss:styles/css`?

Comment: missing sass script

Comment: sass --watch input.scss output.css

Answer (score 0):

you can to check here for sass command

https://sass-lang.com/install

```
you have  install node js?
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sass watch usage](http://sassbreak.com/watch-your-sass/)

If you have Sass installed globally you can use the Sass command and then pass the `scss` file and the `css`-output file as arguments.

`sass source/stylesheets/index.scss build/stylesheets/index.css`

If you want to watch a file you can use this syntax:

`sass --watch input.scss output.css`

or if you want to watch the current directory:

`sass --watch .`

If you want to compile from style.scss to style.css

`sass --watch style.scss:style.css`

If you have your scss/sass and css in separated directories (I assume this is what you want):

`sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css`

Additionally it seems like you haven't installed Sass globally properly.Try reinstalling sass once again.